# On proving a space to be measurable space and finding topology generated by it.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

I am trying to solve an assignment of measure theory of an institute in which I don't study as our professor doesn't give any assignment. I am struct on this question. Can someone please tell how to proceed.

Let $S= \{ s_1  ,  s_2  , \ldots ,  s_ k \}$ , where $k  \le  \infty $ .

Let $B  = \mathcal{P}(S)$ be the power set of $S$, and $ p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_k $ be non negative numbers .

Let
$$
  \lambda(A) =  \sum_{I=1}^k p_i  I_A (  s_i  ) ,
$$
where $ I _A $ is the characteristic (indicator) function of $A$.

I have to prove that

(1)  $( S, B,  \lambda  )$ is a measurable space.

(2) Topology on which it is defined / topology which it induces.

Please help

Comment: Well what have you tried for (1)? And could you elaborate on what exactly do you mean by (2)? As far as I know I don’t see how a measurable space $S$ can induce a topology on $S$, I do know that there’s a well defined metric on some equivalence clases of the $\sigma$-algebra of a measurable space, but it’s not clear whether this is what you’re looking for.

Comment: @ Alonso Delfín it is easy to show that B is a sigma algebra and non negativity of measure.  But the problem is how to prove it to be countably additive and that there exists atleast one set E belonging to B such that measure of E is finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer (1) - and here I am assuming from your notation that $S$ is a finite or countable set - we need to show that $\lambda$ satisfies the definition of a measure. The only tricky part involves the passage to the limit (i.e. countable additivity for disjoint sets), which can be justified using [Tonelli's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli's_theorem_for_non-negative_measurable_function) since everything is non-negative.

For (2), I am assuming you mean to find a topology on $S$ whose Borel $\sigma$-algebra equals $B$. But since $B$ is the power set, all events are measurable so the topology is discrete (i.e., the topology also equals the power set - so in this case, the topology equals the $\sigma$-algebra). As a side note, this is why it is called *discrete* probability.

Comment: can you please show some calculations in proving countable additivity.  I am a beginner in subject also I have a really bad instructor in this course  and how to prove $ \lambda( phi) $ =0

Comment: Showing that $\lambda(\varnothing)=0$ is immediate from the definitions, since (by definition of the indicator function) $I_{\varnothing}(s_i)=0$ for all $s_i$, and adding up a bunch of zeros still gives you zero. Regarding countable additivity, if you substitute the formula for $\lambda(A)$ into the definition of countable additivity you will see that it is one "interchange of summation" away from what you need to show. The theorem that justifies the interchange is exactly the one I quoted. If still stuck, write out the full details of what you have tried and where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: thank you very much